# When applying WriteFiles to an unbounded PCollection, must specify number of output shards explicitly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So far I've been trying to write 1 parquet file per Window object, but I get so many small files in the end that I can't figure out what's going on until I saw a method that I forgot about, `withNumSharsd()`.

I was using it as all the examples lead to that and in development I didn't need more than that.

Once I tested it with much more events, the wall time started to increase exponentially until more than 1 day!

So, digging into the docs in the code it basically says that placing a 0 instead of any other number will lead to run-time specification of those required shards.

When running `mvn compile`, the following message pops up.

```
When applying WriteFiles to an unbounded PCollection, must specify number of output shards explicitly
```

Isn't there an option which allows you to specify the number of shards when deploying the Dataflow job?

I've tried adding `--outputNumShards=20 --errorOutputNumShards=10` to `Dexec.args`.

Comment: Follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1438 to see when this is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you use `WriteFiles` for files writing (all FileBasedSink IOs use it under the hood, like `FileIO`, `TextIO`, etc) then you still need to set number of shards manually by `withNumShards(int)` for unbounded sources and it should be greater than 0 (see: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.16.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/WriteFiles.java#L314)